# How to increase font size inside a table without affecting other table properties?

Tags: tables, fonts, text

I am currently working on a LaTeX document that includes a large table. I need to increase the font size of the text inside this table to enhance readability, but I want to ensure that all other aspects of the table (such as its layout, column widths, and alignment) remain unchanged. The table is set to span the entire text width using `\resizebox` to scale it appropriately. Here is a simplified snippet of my table setup:

```
\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Simplified Example of My Large Table}
\label{tab:simplified_example}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % I've adjusted the row spacing for better readability
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{ c c | c c }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Category 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Category 2}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} \\
\hline
Item 1 & 123 & Item A & ABC \\
Item 2 & 456 & Item B & DEF \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
}
\end{table*}
```

I've attempted to modify the font size using various commands such as `\Large`, placed before the table environment and inside it, but it appears the use of `\resizebox` might be overriding these changes, keeping the font size unchanged.

Is there a method to increase the font size of all text within the table that doesn't interfere with the table's sizing and layout controlled by `\resizebox`? Or perhaps an alternative approach to `\resizebox` that allows for both resizing and font size adjustment?

Comment: never do `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` to tables it ensures you will get inconsistent font sizes and rule widths. as you say choose a font size consistent with the rest of the document `\large` or `\Large` or whetever is needed (used inside `table` before `tabular`, not before `table`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But If I don't use the resizebox, then my table will not get fit into the page.

Comment: then use `\small` or `\footnotesize` or some suitable font size or use column types other than `c` so that you get line breaking in a column.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Please provide more information about your document in general and the large table in particular. E.g., how many columns and rows does the table have? Does it maybe need to be typeset in landscape mode? Which document class do you employ, which font (if not Computer Modern), and which font size?

Comment: For sure, the `\resizebox` approach, aka the sledgehammer approach, has *absolutely no chance* of producing a satisfactory table. In particular, any attempt on your part to enlarge the font size is going to be thwarted automatically by the action of `\resizebox`.